# Remote user is not able to connect to mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

MariaDB is installed on server with IP 1.2.3.4, new MySQL user has been created on 1.2.3.4 for remote IP a.b.c.d, but while trying to connect MySQL on 1.2.3.4 from a.b.c.d giving error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '1.2.3.4' (111
> "Connection refused")

Investigation-:

1. trying to telnet from a.b.c.d to 1.2.3.4 at port 3306 also not working
2. surprisingly when trying to connect mysql from 1.2.3.4 directly using server IP 1.2.3.4 is also throwing error "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '1.2.3.4' (111)
3. While trying to connect mysql using mysql -h localhost -u root -p is successfully working.

What we are looking for, we want to connect mysql from a.b.c.d to 1.2.3.4, please suggest what we are missing.

addtional information:

1. on server 1.2.3.4 /etc/mysql/my.cnf is not present, there exist '/etc/my.cnf'
2. trying to find solution we are referring link "webdock.io/en/docs/how-guides/database-guides/…" some edit is mentioned to in file "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" which is not present.

Added from comment below

Firewall has been disabled, user has already created, mariadb.log showing error while binding

```
221215 17:10:12 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 99: Cannot assign requested address 
221215 17:10:12 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ? 
221215 17:10:12 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Well if mariaDB has not been started then of course you will get a `connection refused`. There is nothing there to make a connection to. So it looks like you have some other process that has already grabbed port 3306. Did they also install MySQL by any chance? Has that started automatically? that would be the most likely server to grab 3306

Comment: `netstat -tulpn | grep :3306` find out what is using port 3306

Comment: riggsfolly-: output of  "netstat -tulpn | grep :3306" is  "tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30754/mysqld"

Comment: So assuming you have not got mariadb working, then that looks like you already have a MySQL or mariaDB already running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points to consider.

1. Check firewall (port 3306 should be allowed for the remote ip if you are running MariaDB on 3306 port )
2. The user should exists (which you have) and it should be something like;

   user@your_remote_ip
3. Check bind-address in the configuration file, if it set to `127.0.0.1` it will allow only localhost login.
4. It is a good idea to check the logs , usually located on `/var/log/mysql/` or you could verify from the configuration file where the logs are located

   log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

Comment: ergest basha, firewall has been disabled, user has already created, mariadb.log showing error while binding 221215 17:10:12 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 99: Cannot assign requested address
221215 17:10:12 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
221215 17:10:12 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: @champs and the bind-address ? What is the output of  `ip a` ?

Comment: output of ip a-: ens192: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.50.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.10.50.255
        inet6 fe80::2e43:639a:2e2d:f49c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:c1:a5:38  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 130565636  bytes 33830009699 (31.5 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 15620  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 107701714  bytes 37841666005 (35.2 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: remaining output of above-: lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 135724757  bytes 13217170608 (12.3 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 135724757  bytes 13217170608 (12.3 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: ergest Basha-: in file /etc/my.cnf there is no bind-address parameter mentioned.

Comment: Please put that ouput into your question, nobody can read this stuff in a comment

Comment: @champs check all the configuration files , it might be on different path. I doubt that it isn't because it comes with the default configuration. If it isn't you can add it and then reboot the mysql server

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it might be a firewall issue.

Make sure that the port on which the database server is running is not closed and is exposed publicly.

Also check if the database configurations allow binding IP is not only set to 127.0.0.1 but every IP can bind.